Removing certains values from an array

Write a JavaScript function to remove. null, 0, "", false, undefined and NaN values from an array.

Sample array
[NaN, 0, 15, false, -22, '',undefined, 47, null]

Expected result
[15, -22, 47] 

I am getting the result as : [ NaN ]
Is there any other way to perform this action?*


const arr = [0, NaN, 15, false, -22, '', undefined, 47, null]
let result = []

for (let i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++) {

  if (arr[i] !== 0 && arr[i] !== false && arr[i] !== '' && arr[i] !== undefined && arr[i] !== null && !isNaN(arr[i]) === false) {

    result.push(arr[i])
  }
}

console.log(result)




arr.filter(v => v); ..?

arr.filter(Boolean) too.

The reason the orignal code doesn't work is because there shouldn't be a ! in !isNaN(arr[i]) === false. But yes, I assume the exercise is about teaching falsey values so you shouldn't be checking each of them separately.

Does this answer your question? Remove all falsy values from an array

Looks like you want to keep truthy values. You can pass filter and just use the value itself as the predicate using the identity function (x => x).


const arr = [0, NaN, 15, false, -22, '', undefined, 47, null]
const result = arr.filter(a => a)

console.log(result)



If filter doesn't work for you, it's the equivalent of looping over the input, and if a condition is true, adding it to the output one:


const arr = [0, NaN, 15, false, -22, '', undefined, 47, null]
const result = []

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  const item = arr[i];
  if (item) {
    result.push(item);
  }
}

console.log(result)



Notice how the main point is that we are exploiting the concept of truthiness in JavaScript: every value at runtime can be evaluated as either true or false, regardless of whether they are a boolean or not. 0, NaN, false, undefined, and null are all evaluated to false when a boolean is required (like when expressing a condition for an if statement), while non-zero numbers are all evaluated to true.
For more on the concept and how JavaScript decides whether a value is truthy or not, you can read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy

yes, that  works better

Edited my reply to give a few alternatives. If this is about learning, the concept of truthiness is probably the one to learn here. Not sure of course.

don't recommend for...in on an array, especially to a beginner. see: MDN: Array iteration and for...in. Also declare your variable in your loop.

you can filter the array to include only the numbers. The main issue in your code is the condition !isNaN(arr[i]) === false, which is not working as expected. Instead, you can use the typeof operator to check if the value is a number and isFinite to ensure it is not NaN.


const arr = [NaN, 0, 15, false, -22, '', undefined, 47, null];
let result = [];

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (typeof arr[i] === 'number' && arr[i] !== 0 && isFinite(arr[i])) {
    result.push(arr[i]);
  }
}

console.log(result); // [15, -22, 47]



Alternatively, you can use the filter method,


const arr = [NaN, 0, 15, false, -22, '', undefined, 47, null];

const result = arr.filter(item => typeof item === 'number' && item !== 0 && isFinite(item));

console.log(result); // [15, -22, 47]




But, your code is giving the result [ 0, 15, -22, 47 ] and expected result is [15, -22, 47 ]
